# Perl Mechanize submit button

Tags: perl, web, submit, mechanize

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use WWW::Mechanize

$adres = qq{http://debian.ds/};
$mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->get( $adres );
$mech->click( 'agreed' );
print $mech->content;
```

#

and I get:
No clickable input with name agreed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/WWW/Mechanize.pm line 1707.

Html look like this:

```
<fieldset class="submit-buttons">
<input type="submit" name="agreed" id="agreed" value="text1" class="button1" />&nbsp;
<input type="submit" name="not_agreed" value="text2" class="button2" />
<input type="hidden" name="change_lang" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="creation_time" value="1373067606" />
<input type="hidden" name="form_token" value="83ab2ec47bc4ee37f" />
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to select the form you wish to use first.

from CPAN on WWW::Mechanize

```
$mech->forms

Lists all the forms on the current page. Each form is an HTML::Form object. In list    context, returns a list of all forms. In scalar context, returns an array reference of all   forms.

$mech->form_number($number)

Selects the numberth form on the page as the target for subsequent calls to "field()" and   "click()". Also returns the form that was selected.

If it is found, the form is returned as an HTML::Form object and set internally for later      use with Mech's form methods such as "field()" and "click()".

Emits a warning and returns undef if no form is found.

The first form is number 1, not zero.
```

Comment: This is not necessary when the forms have unique characteristics, which in practice they always have.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new;
$mech->get('file:///tmp/so17498270.html');
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        agreed => 'text1',
    }
);
```